# Как реализовать Singleton в C

Tags: c, singleton

Имеется функция, которую планируется вызывать многократно. Функция использует внутри некоторое кол-во структур, однако после инициализации структуры будут только читаться.
Поэтому у меня появилась идея условно проинициализировать структуры только во время первого вызова функции и освободить память на последнем вызове.

Стоит добавить, что эти структуры не зависят от внешних данных, поэтому не вижу смысла в передачи их через аргументы функции.

Как это грамотно сделать? Есть ли варианты избежать использования глобальных функций? И как это делают обычно?

---

**UPD**:
Меня попросили добавить модельный пример.
Как видно из модели, инициализация ***dict1*** и ***dict2*** будет происходить при каждом вызове функции, чего хотелось бы избежать.

P. S. На самом деле на скорость работы функции сильно не влияет инициализация. Но мне просто интересно, как от такого рода накладных расходов избавляются на практике.

```
// func лежит в другом файле
int func(char *in_str, char* out_str){
    struct dictionary dict1 = init1(...); // Не зависит от аргументов
    struct dictionary dict2 = init2(...); // Не зависит от аргументов

    /*
        .........
    */ 

   return result;
}   


int main(){

    /*
        Многократный вызов func()
    */
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Есть идея лучше - инициализировать структуры еще до первого обращения. А еще лучше - инициализировать еще во время компиляции.

Comment: статическая переменная внутри функции имеет область видимости только внутри неё. инициализируется только один первый раз. такое надо ?

Comment: @user7860670 Можно пример того как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: @AlexGlebe Я думал, но как тогда функции передать информацию о том, что нужно освободить память? Можно, конечно, добавить флаг в аргументы функции, но выглядит не очень.

Comment: можно эту статическую переменную с функцией отдельно разместить в одном файле. `static int secret = .. ; void secretInit ( void ) { ... } void secretDestroy ( void ) { ... } void func ( void ) { .. используем secret .. }`

Comment: Какую память надо освободить? Если надо освободить память из под синглтона, это не синглтон а обычный глобальный объект с конечным временем жизни, каких может быть много.

Comment: @AlexGlebe "инициализируется только один первый раз" - это в С++ так, в С можно инициализировать только константой времени компиляции.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, я добавил модельный пример.

Comment: До первого вызова `func` вызвать `init`, после последнего вызвать `term`. Чем плохо?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, в таком случае придется использовать глобальные переменные скорее всего. А мне интересно есть ли варианты без глобальных переменных. Я просто видел, что рекомендуется использовать как можно меньше глобальных переменных. Или static достаточно защищает глобальные переменные?

Comment: Поместите функции в отдельный файл. Переменные статические в этом файле. Не вижу проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать как-то так:

```
/* это отдельный от main файл */
static struct dictionary dict1;
static struct dictionary dict1;
static int do_dicts_init = 1;

int func(char *in_str, char* out_str){
    if (do_dicts_init) {
        dict1 = init1(...);
        dict2 = init2(...);
        do_dicts_init = 0;
    }

    /*
        .........
    */ 

   return result;
}   

/* если требуется повторное использование серии вызовов func() */
void destroy_dicts () {
     do_dicts_init = 0;
     free_dict1_mem (&dict1);
     free_dict2_mem (&dict2);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!